# How to get app information from bundle ID

Tags: ios, objective-c

Right now I only have the bundle ID of another program such as "`com.apple.AddressBook`" without its info.plist file, then i want to get the app version/app name from "`com.apple.AddressBook`", how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want exactly but i am trying to answer you based on what i am getting.

I think you want to find app name/version from bundle identifier.
Please try as below

```
NSString *appName = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"BundleIdentifierOfApp"] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(id)kCFBundleExecutableKey];
NSString *appVersion = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"BundleIdentifierOfApp"] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSLog(@"AppName: %@ \n appVersion: %@",appName, appVersion );
```